# Handling websocket connection the right way in React Native with redux-observable

Tags: react-native, redux, websocket, rxjs, redux-observable

I am working on a React Native app, in which I'm using `redux-observable` as a `redux` middleware for managing the app state. I have a websocket connection which is basically setup this way:

```
let websocket: WebSocket;

export function connect() {
    websocket = new WebSocket("wss://test.foo.com/abc"));

    websocket.addEventListener("open", () => getStore().dispatch(websocketOpen()));
    websocket.addEventListener("close", () => getStore().dispatch(websocketClosed()));
    websocket.addEventListener("error", () => getStore().dispatch(websocketClosed()));
    websocket.addEventListener("message",
        (message: Event & {data: string}) => getStore().dispatch(websocketMessage(
            JSON.parse(message.data),
        )));
}
```

I am handling the `websocketClosed` action with a redux-observable epic:

```
const reopenWebsocket: Epic = (action$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(WEBSOCKET_CLOSED),
        tap(websocket.connect),
        ignoreElements(),
    );
```

This works fine except that the server is constantly breaking because of a lot of websocket requests.

I suppose that if `connect` is ever called when a websocket is already open, the old websocket is replaced
so the old websocket's close event is triggered, which I'm guessing results in a `websocket.connect`, which in turn triggers the new websocket's close event.

I'm not sure what I could be doing more to handle connection to the websocket better in the app, so the server isn't spammed with numerous requests which seem avoidable.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion/solution to this.